# Facebook sream.publish not showing attachment thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-stream-story

I am posting a flash widget on facebook via facebook php sdk using facebook stream.publish. The attachment has swf source and image source etc. For some images, the thumbnail is not loaded and rather a 1x1 image is loaded. Whereas the imgsrc points to a valid image url with no security or firewall or any kind of blockage.
The flash can not be played because the user can't really click on a 1x1 image. I'm stuck on this with no help from facebook documentation. Plz help

Comment: Did you try to use the debug tool to check your URL? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yeah I did, and it gives an error, "unable to download data from given url". The response code is 206.
But the image opens in the browser just fine

Comment: Any chance you could share the URL so I can take a look? :)

Comment: The image urls from shopping.com products do the problem. So I'm using a fixed image placed on my own server